# QML darag&drop error "grabToImage: item's window is not visible"

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, qml

I have mainwindow.ui with `quickWidget` where I try to make drag drop. But I get error when drag element.

C++ code:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{

    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->m_quickWidget->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/QmlDragAndDrop.qml"));
    ui->m_quickWidget->setClearColor(Qt::transparent);
    ui->m_quickWidget->setResizeMode(QQuickWidget::SizeRootObjectToView);
}
```

QML code:

```
Item {
    width: 350
    height: 400

    Component{
        id: dragColor
        Rectangle {
            property int id: 0

            id: tile
            width: text.implicitWidth + 20; height: text.implicitHeight + 10
            color: "green"
            radius: 5

            Drag.active: mouseArea.drag.active;
            Drag.supportedActions: Qt.CopyAction;
            Drag.dragType: Drag.Automatic;
            Drag.mimeData: {"color": tile.color, "width": tile.width, "height": tile.height}

            Text {
                id: text
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: "Drag me"
            }

            MouseArea {
                id: mouseArea
                anchors.fill: parent
                drag.target: parent

                onPressed: tile.grabToImage(function(result) {
                    parent.Drag.imageSource = result.url
                    typeElement = dragColor
                })

                onReleased: {
                    if(parent.Drag.supportedActions === Qt.CopyAction){
                        tile.x=0
                        tile.y=0
                        typeElement = 0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Row {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        anchors.margins: 4;
        Loader {
            z: 2;
            sourceComponent: dragColor;
        }

        Loader {
            z: 2;
            sourceComponent: dragColor;
            onLoaded: item.color = "yellow";
        }
    }
}
```

Drag works if I use `QQuickView` instead of `QQuickWidget`, but it creates other window. Can drag works in `QQuickWidget`?

Comment: I recall this: https://forum.qt.io/topic/49814/solved-qquickwidget-doesn-t-accept-drops

Comment: Could you use `QQuickView` instead? Or maybe `QQmlApplicationEngine`?